# Redshift database size grew sagnificantly when the cluster was resized

Tags: amazon-redshift, cluster-computing

In Redshift I had a cluster with 4 nodes of the type dc2.large
The total size of the cluster was 160*4=640gb. The system showed 100% storage full. The size of the database was close to 640gb
Query I use to check the size of the db:

```
select sum(used_mb) from (
     SELECT schema  as table_schema,
            "table" as table_name,
            size    as used_mb
     FROM svv_table_info d order by size desc
 )
```

I added 2 dc2.large nodes - classic resize which set the size of the cluster to 160*6=960gb, but when I checked the size of the database suddenly I saw that it also grew and again takes almost 100% of the cluster with increased size.
Database size grew with the size of the cluster!
I had to perform additional resize operation - elastic one. From 6 nodes to 12 nodes. The size of the data remained close to 960gb
How is it possible that the size of the database grew from 640gb to 960gb as a result of cluster resize operation?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that your database has a lot of small tables in it.  There are other ways this can happen but this is by far the most likely cause.  You see Redshift uses a 1MB "block" as the minimum storage unit which is great for large data table storage but is inefficient for small (< 1M rows per slice in the cluster).

If you have a table that has say 100K rows split across your 4 nodes of dc2.large nodes (8 slices), each slice holds 12.5K rows.  Each column for this table will need 1 block (1MB) to store the data.  However, a block on average can store 200K rows (per column) so most of the blocks for this table are mostly empty.  If you add rows the on-disk size (post vacuum) doesn't increase.  Now if you add 50% more nodes you are also adding 50% more slices which just adds 50% more nearly empty blocks to the table's storage.

If this isn't your case I can expand on other ways this can happen but this really is the most likely in my experience.  Unfortunately the fix for this is often to revamp your data model or to offload some less used data to Spectrum (S3).